# How to check if an Android Thread is running

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is there a way to check if a Thread object has had start called on it already?

I'm trying to so something like:

```
if(rt.isAlive() == true)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "START RECORD");
    rt.recording = true;
}
else
{
    Log.v(TAG, "START THREAD/RECORD");

    rt.start();
}
```

where it would start the thread if it's not already running.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that `rt` is a `Thread`, just check `rt.isAlive()`.

Alternatively, just use a boolean flag and set it to true right before you start your thread.

I would actually prefer the boolean approach so there is no way that the main thread could start the other thread twice - there may be a short delay until your Thread is up and running, and if your main thread tries to start the thread twice in quick succession, it may get a "false" negative on `rt.isAlive()`.

Comment: isAlive keeps returning false for me somehow(I just updated my answer to reflect my code.) Using the boolean should work though as I'm already using one to stop my internal Thread loop.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah that worked.  Basically I don't initialize the Thread until the action is hit, then I check my internal thread bool after that.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! The only thing I want to reiterate is that you need to be aware of the delay between starting a thread and having it run - if you set a bool in your Thread's `run` method, there's a short period of time where you started the thread, but the bool isn't set to true yet. That's why I recommend setting it in the main thread.

Comment: EboMike: are you actually seeing isAlive() returning false?  Starting in Eclair, the isAlive() function just returns "vmThread != null", and the vmThread field is set by the VM before pthread_create is called.  If the main thread calls start(), any subsequent isAlive() call from the main thread will return true.  Thread creation is not asynchronous.  (In donut and earlier, isAlive() worked differently, but should still be reliably returning "true" after calling create().)

Comment: It's fadden! Long time no see! I've never used isAlive() myself, I just waded through the documentation and it seemed like something that would do the trick here. Btw - good to know about thread synchronization not being asynchronous (although, to be fair, it is presumably still not defined how long it will take until the first instruction of the thread's `run()` method is executed).

Comment: You don't know how long thread startup will take, and once the thread has been started you don't know whether the "old" or "new" thread will get to execute first.  All you know is that the new thread will be "runnable".

Answer (score 7):

I've used this approach with success:

```
if ( mythread.getState() == Thead.State.NEW )
    //then we have a brand new thread not started yet, lets start it
    mythread.start();
else
    //it is running already compensate
```

Answer (score 2):

If you called start on it, and it is running, you will get an `IllegalThreadStateException`.  Catching that is one way to know.

Another option is to extend Thread and add a boolean where you keep track of whether or not your Thread has been started.  You can override the start method of Thread to check the boolean before calling up to `super.start()`.

You should be very careful when using threads in Android though.  Make sure you understand the lifecycle of the component that is starting it.  Also, you should consider some of the helper classes like Handler and AsyncTask instead of directly spawning threads.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.  I think we both agree that needing to do it doesn't pass the sniff test.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how to use Threads which is mainly what this is about.  I'm using my own implementation of Thread in a separate class so using a Runnable won't work, but the boolean method by itself should.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to make you aware that you need to consider the environment in Android.  It is very different than standard desktop Java, even though the syntax for threading is the same.

Comment: That's what I've seen from the documentation.  My background is c though.  I've never done Java Threading. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call this method by passing a thread. It will check the thread is alive or not, every 500 milliseconds with start delay of 500 milliseconds (you can use your custom values). I use this method often.

```
void threadAliveChecker(final Thread thread) {
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!thread.isAlive()) {
                       // do your work after thread finish

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // do the ui work here
                        }
                    });
                    timer.cancel();
                }else {
                      // do work when thread is running like show progress bar
                  }
            }
        }, 500, 500);  // first is delay, second is period
    }
```

Example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
thread.start();
threadIsAliveChecker(thread);
```

This method will let us know when the thread is finished doing its work.